# Create component of rich Text with Table creation

Tags: lightning, table, richtextarea, component

I wonder how can I add more tools to lightning rich text, like - create a table tool.

For example - this:

```
<lightning:inputRichText value="{!v.myVal}" placeholder="hi!"/>
```

render to this: 
[image]

If I create a table in Word document and copy past it to my rich text field - Its copied and displayed as well.

But what if I want to create the table inside the rich text? Should I need to create the element of the table in the code or there is a way to add the Icon of the table creating to the lightning:richText tools?

Like this :

[image]

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible anymore with the built-in Richtext editor.

According to https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000313235&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1 : "Tables cannot be added via the UI; however they can be added via API (APEX script sample below):"

It is a great step, my users love it :-(

Comment: It's really unfortunate that they removed it.
Thank you very much.